# Event Receiver issue with updating Splistitem fields only when i save as a document from Office Word?

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

I have a problem with updating Splistitem fields only when i save as via Office Word a document to Sharepoint in my Event receiver.

it's works when i add the document from Sharepoint.

here is my Code :

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    properties.ListItem["Status"] = "Approved";
}
```

Comment: properties.ListItem.Update() to apply the changes :)

Comment: Still didn't Work,an properties.ListItem.Update() fire my other Event (ItemUpdating) which is not my case.

it's crazy, cause when i add the document from sharepoint it's work without a Update()!

Comment: bool eventFiring = this.EventFiringEnabled; this.EventFiringEnabled = false; properties.ListItem.Update(); this.EventFiringEnabled = eventFiring;
So the Update won't fire any other event ;)